# Using variable in a value field in jMeter

Tags: variables, jmeter

1. I've added a User Defined Variables element

   - Then created a variable ${Parameter} with value "123456" and passed it in a GET request.
   - Created a second variable ${Response} with value "Invalid code 123456"
2. I've added a Response Assertion element

   - Added the ${Response} variable to the Response Assertion

When I send the request like this, everything is fine. But if I add the second variable in the value field, then an Assertion error is returned.

What I'm trying to do is to add a variable to the value field of an already existing variable:
e.g. Set the Value of the ${Response} variable as "Invalid code ${Parameter}"

How can I achieve this in jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you unnecessarily making the things complex!

You can directly use the value you want to assert in the `Response Assertion`.

Keep as follows:

```
Invalid code ${Parameter}
```

Here, ${Parameter} value be evaluated first and checked against the response.

---

Just incase, if you want to use JMeter variable as value to another JMeter variable, use as follows, using `${__evalVar()}`:

```
Invalid code ${__evalVar(Parameter)}
```

Note: observed that if you define both the variables in the same UDV, `Parameter` value is empty. So, add two UDVs and define `Parameter` in the first UDV and `Response` in the second UDV with above value.