# Jmeter : Reading variable from csv and pass it into another varaible

Tags: parsing, jmeter

I want to read a variable from CSV and use that value into another variable. 
Example:
I have a variable as: 
`${url}: wwww.$(value_from_csv}.com`

and secondary url `${url}/xyz`

In my Jmeter script, ${value_from_csv} is not passed.

What I am missing?

Comment: try with `__evalVar` function. here is my detailed answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41287325/2575259

Comment: thank you. it worked. But MongoDB Source Config doesn't read variable from CSV.
Example: 
**Server Address List : ${address_from_csv}**
but it doesn't read variables from csv.
_ ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${address_from_csv}: nodename nor servname provided, or not known_
can you help me on this??

Comment: I don't understand the question fully. please add all necessary details. like test plan, where you defined `address_from_csv` and how are using it etc.

Comment: I have a CSV which contains variable **Server Address List** and other variables used in my script. In **MongoDb Source Config" I input **Server Address List as ${address_from_csv}** where address_from_csv is the server address of my mongoDB. But the problem is, MongoDb Source Config doesn't read variable value(address_from_csv) from CSV. On the other hand, other variables from CSV is working fine. Which implies there is no error in CSV Data Set Config.

Comment: can you please show me the test plan screenshot?

Comment: @Naveen please find the screenshot https://s24.postimg.org/8cudoufwl/Screen_Shot_2016_12_29_at_2_20_03_PM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observed that `CSV Dataset Config` values are not passed (not available) to any of the Config Elements irrespective of the order of the components (Config Elements) in JMeter Test Plan (checked with `User Defined Config` & `MongoDB Source Config`), though passed to Samplers.

so, suggested the OP to define the value in `jmeter.properties` instead of a CSV file, so we can access `user.host` in `MongoDB Source Config`.

Steps:

1. Add `user.host=address` in `jmeter.properties`
2. Restart Jmeter
3. Add `${__P(user.host,)}` in `Server Address List` field in `MongoDB Source Config`

Note: In case of running JMeter script from Jenkins, property will be picked by the script, from `jmeter.properites` file.

Comment: https://s24.postimg.org/8cudoufwl/Screen_Shot_2016_12_29_at_2_20_03_PM.png 
I don't think this issue is because of ordering. Please refer to the screen shot for more info.

Comment: Thanks. will look into it. meanwhile, please share the CSV file content and CSV Dataset Config screenshot also

Comment: Here is the screenshot of csv data set config https://s30.postimg.org/51sc10mzl/Screen_Shot_2016_12_29_at_2_28_51_PM.png

the other variables used in my script is working fine except the variable used in MongoDb Source Config.So, i think the issue is with mongodb config.
Thanks

Comment: Checked. It seems CSV Dataset Config values are not available to other Config elements, checked with User Defined Variables also, but available to Samplers. so, there is no way you can use the value from the CSV file. But, From User Defined Variables/Test Plan, you can access the variables. so, you have to try with one of them. define `address` as a User Defined variable or in Test Plan, and access it MongoDb Source Config. I tried, it is working.

Comment: I was using the variable from User Defined Variable before. But now I need to read that variable from CSV because I have multiple .jmx file which need same variable.

Comment: why don't you configure it as Property in `jmeter.properties` and access it as `__P()`. eg: keep `user.host=localhost` and restart the JMeter, in the script you can access it as `${__P(user.host,)}`. it is working. Property is available to all JMX files which are running using same JMeter batch file.

Comment: Yeah, that will work if I configure it in `jmeter.properties` but the problem will occur if I execute my script from **Jenkins**. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Well, I don't find any issue as it is picking the value from `jmeter.properties` file when ran using Jenkins. when you configure batch command, jmeter.bat will always load properties from `jmeter.properties`.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I will try :) Thank you for all your effort and replying all my queries :)

Comment: The best way of saying thanks is to accept and Upvote the answer. I can see that none of the questions asked by you, have the accepted answer. I think it is just lack of knowledge. so I request you to go and accept the answer for all your questions, in case they really helped/solved your issue. This will help other community members who face the similar issues and use the accepted answer. I am saying all these as you are new to SO! :)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Source Config is initialized **before** any JMeter Variables so the only way to make it dynamic is using JMeter Properties instead.

You can set a JMeter Property in 2 ways:

1. Define it in *user.properties* file like:

   ```
   server.address.1=some.ip.or.hostname.1
   server.address.2=some.ip.or.hostname.2
   ```
2. Pass the properties via `-J` command-line arguments like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jserver.address.1=some.ip.or.hostname.1 -Jserver.address.2=some.ip.or.hostname.2 ....
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on using JMeter Properties